# how to check, if the input field contains any value in protractor tests

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

I would like to check if the input field contains any string or not. From the below code snippet, how can I check ? it actually contains **Asset Management**.

```
<input _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-md-3 mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="title" matinput="" placeholder="Object Title" type="text" ng-reflect-model="Asset Management" ng-reflect-id="title" ng-reflect-placeholder="Object Title" ng-reflect-type="text" aria-describedby="mat-hint-2" aria-invalid="false">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a way to select your input, one example :

```
beforeEach(function() {
    input = element(by.id('title'));
  });
```

then in your test you can do :

```
expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('Asset Management')
```

If you just want to see if there is any value :

```
expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBeTruthy()
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I would like to check if input.getAttribute('value') contains any not only Asset Management.

Thanks in advance